# Hello, how can I change the size of the Android Studio selector

Tags: flutter, android-studio

how can I change the size of the Android Studio selector

Hello, how can I reduce the size of the Android Studio selector, after opening the Android Studio, the size of the selector is automatically increased, please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbGL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you pressed the "insert" button on your keyboard by mistake. press it again and it will go back to normal

the insert button is usually above the arrow keys, near "Home", "Page Up" ..etc

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved. I had pressed the insert button